# Why is Fragment.onResume() not displaying my GUI until after onResume finishes completely?

Tags: android, android-fragments, visibility, onresume, motorola-emdk

I am writing an Android application that interfaces with the Motorola EMDK, and I am running into an issue with timing/threading.  I have an activity that adds a fragment to perform a very specific function using the EMDK, displays a screen that tells the user what is happening and then is cleaned up by the activity after about 15 seconds.

I am noticing a 1-2 second delay between when the EMDK action occurs, in this case the device cradle is being unlocked, and when the GUI is displayed that says "The cradle is now unlocked."

I have done some research about how Android handles drawing to the screen for fragments, and everything I can find says that onResume is called "when the fragment becomes visible."  This does not match my experience, however.  According to how I understand the code below should work, the screen should be drawn and then the EMDKManager.getEMDKManager() method is called, which constructs a pointer to the EMDK service and creates a new thread to perform the unlock:

```
@Override  
public void onResume() {  
      super.onResume();  
      EMDKManager.getEMDKManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), this);  
}
```

It looks more like the screen is drawn to only once onResume() completes in entirety, ie EMDKManager.getEMDKManager() finishes its call as well.

As the fragment is the EMDKListener object that is required for the second parameter for the method, I am struggling finding a way to thread this correctly.  I need the GUI to be drawn first or at the same time that the cradle unlock occurs.

**Are there any other methods that can be overridden or interfaced with to get the equivalent to an onViewDrawn() event for the fragment?**

Thank you very much.

Comment: Because that's how works ui thread and messages queue...

Comment: That was the most unhelpful comment ever.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All the lifecycle method `onCreate()`, `onResume()` `onStop()` etc. are called by the main thread, which is also responsible for drawing the UI.

By preforming a long operation in those method, you block the UI thread from handling touch input as well as drawing the app

you can start your long operation on another thread by doing so:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       // do long operations here
    }
}.start();
```

note that if that operation wants to update the UI components it MUST be done on the UI thread, you can do so by passing a runnable to the activity

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // do UI updating but, do not block it here
    }
});
```

(or you can create an handler if it's a `Service` or you want to delay those runnables)

Comment: "As the fragment is the EMDKListener object that is required for the second parameter for the method, I am struggling finding a way to thread this correctly."

How would you recommend I reference the fragment as the EMDKListener from within the Runnable?  "this" no longer points to the fragment in the scope of the Runnable.

EMDKManager.getEMDKManager(Context, EMDKListener);

Comment: `MyAcitivity.this` will refer to the activity in an anonymous class

Comment: I need to point to the FRAGMENT not the activity.

EMDKManager.getEMDKManager(Context, EMDKListener);

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: MyFragment.this and MyActivity.this do not work by the way.  In the context of the specific class I am in it would be UnlockFragment.this; which isn't a statement according to Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have huge concerns about memory use/leaks, I did this in order to get the timing right:

```
private EMDKManager.EMDKListener getThis() {

    return this;
}

private Runnable initEMDK = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        EMDKManager.getEMDKManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getThis());
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "Starting");
    new Thread(initEMDK).start();
}
```

I feel like there is a standard way of doing the getThis() method.  If you know it, I would love to know.

Thank you.

Comment: FYI by posting on handler, you still do it on the UI thread, but you delay it a bit, until the next pass, so it might not be want you want. anyway I'm not sure what this EMDK does, so I'm not sure

Comment: just switched to your recommended new Thread(initEMDK).start();

so that is a big help. Thank you.

As I am playing with this more, it still doesn't fix the problem.  Something is still hanging the UI/system thread.

Comment: I would not call EMDKManager.getEMDKManager on non ui thread... Seems like problem are not with this call as it looks nice callback... I took a look at documentation and samples and I'm pretty sure that you rather not follow it...  and doing fx scanner.read() on ui thread...

Comment: I have posted in Zebra Dev forums to see if we can track down what is happening.  Can you elaborate on why you would not call that method on a non-UI thread?

Comment: Mostly because it is not stated directly in doc that you can, I I don't know what it does internally...  Fx if it creates and run AsyncTask it would fail...  If it obtain a Handler which supposed to be obtained on ui thread it will fail... Did you measure time how much takes this method call?